# Using Python Script to set Database export to append

Tags: python, scripting, spss, spss-modeler

I've a Python script for SPSS Modeler that will loop over all rows in a table, perform some basic data processing, and export each row of output into a database.  I've included a simplified version of Python my script below.

Unfortunately, I get the following error on the line `pipeline_DB.run(results)`:

> Error: AEQMJ0100E: Script error (Server exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) on line 75 column

In the SPSS Legacy version of this script, I've set the database write mode to append.  I have difficulty doing the same via Python.

**SPSS Modeler Legacy Script**

```
execute 'Pipeline DB table'
set 'Pipeline DB table'.delete_existing_rows = "False"
```

**Python Script**

```
results = []

for i in range(job_rows):
    jobid = job_rowset.getValueAt(i, 0); 

    # set the parameter values and caption of the graph, and the output name
    diagram.setParameterValue ('JOBID_Param', jobid)

    # run the database export node node
    pipeline_DB.run(results)
```